# Facebook API error code 190, subcode 460 in Meteor app even after refreshing login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I use `accounts-facebook` in Meteor 1.4.3.2 to allow my app's users to log in via Facebook. The app also makes other Facebook API calls using the Facebook token `accounts-facebook` stores in the user document.

Sometimes, when I try to make a call, I get an error:

```
{
  message: 'Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 190,
  error_subcode: 460,
  fbtrace_id: '...'
}
```

[Facebook says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errorsubcodes) users will need to log in again. I built a flow to fix this problem. When we get a 190/460, we set the `services.facebook.accessToken` property in their user document to `false` and email them a link to a page with a "Refresh Facebook Login" button which simply logs them in to the app again via Facebook.

The flow appears to work. I can see the `accessToken` gets set to false. When I click through on the link in the email and then click the "Refresh" button, I get a token that is different from the previous token. However, when the app tries to make another FB API request, it gets the same 190/460 error with the new token.

If the fix for 190/460 is to have the user log in again, why do I continue to get the error after the user has refreshed the token?

Comment: Did you get the solution of this?

Comment: @NimishaPatel I did not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it going to Facebook developer page

-> Messenger option from the left menu
-> Configuration

then scroll to "access tokens", click "generate token" button and copy that token to your code.

For example in php looks like

```
   $accessToken = 'EAAKHOkhtsDABAJgyp....';
```